# Schalage deadbolt lock stuck

Tags: repair, doors, lock

Is there anyway to open this lock? I tried a lot but it doesn't budge! Attaching some pics and a [video](https://cl.ly/1L031u0z3U1P) of the lock.

Appreciate your help
[image]
[image]